# I can't excute software project in visual studio, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm learning software developer and got this project of git hub to learn.
https://github.com/the-best-flash/CSharpMiner

The project's creator give us the follow instructions to execute this project in visual studio,  but I don't understand the step number 2, (Change the dropdown that says "Debug" to say "Release")

***project's  instructions**:

1. Load the solution file. *.sln
2. Change the dropdown that says "Debug" to say "Release"
3. Select "Build -> Build Solution"
4. Navigate to the CSharpMinerProgram\bin\Release folder and copy the .exe, and .dll files to wherever you want to run the program from. (ex. C:\CSMiner)
5. Make a \bin folder wherever you put the .exe (ex. C:\CSMiner\bin)
6. Copy the .dll files from CSharpMinerProgram\bin\Release\bin to the \bin folder you just made.
7. Create a "config.conf" file in the same folder as the .exe (ex. C:\CSMiner\bin) you can follow the example further down.
8. Right click on the .exe and make a shortcut. Copy the shortcut to your desktop.*

**I tried follow the project's instructions but appear this error:**
[image]

Comment: Is the error displayed when clicking the .exe file?

Comment: this is a class library not executable project. I't only can be referenced

Comment: Also, step 2 refers to changing the configuration of the active solution. On the Visual Studio toolbar, there is a combo that says "Debug". Click and change to Release

Comment: right click your application and click select a "set as Startup Project"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class Libraries are not executable program.

You should right click CSahrpMinerProgram and select "Set as Startup Project"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When i cloned and opened it up, the wrong project was selected as the startup project.

Click this
[image]